# Saving a list of AWS S3 bucket content and downloading filtered content of list

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have this problem that I am trying to solve, but I cannot find an answer. The problem is actually 2-fold. The first part related to listing all the files in an s3 bucket in AWS. The second part is to download the files that I choose from that list.

**Part 1: Listing all the files**

So, I know how to print a list of all the files:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
                     aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my bucket')

for s3_file in bucket.objects.all():
    print(s3_file.key)
```

Now, for my future work, I need to keep the filenames in a list that I can extract specific filename from (i.e. they are csv-file with a specific part of name). So I, though that I would modify the above code to:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
                     aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my bucket')
my_files =[]
for s3_file in bucket.objects.all():
     my_files.append(outputfilename)
```

but this does not work because it returns a list of files with only the first filename

```
['020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
 '020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv',
and so on]
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

**Part 2: Downloading all files in list**

Given that I have managed to save a list of files, I need to download them locally. Now, to do so, I found this code:

```
filenames = list
for i in filenames:
    filename = i
    #print(i)
    bucket_name = 'my bucket'


    
    outputfilename = filename[1:] 
    outputfilename = outputfilename.replace(':','_')

    session = Session(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
                     aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    your_bucket = s3.Bucket('my bucket')

    s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    s3.download_file(bucket_name,filename,outputfilename)
    print(outputfilename)
```

but it doesn't download locally. I am completely new to this, have googled all possible solutions, read most post on SO, but cannot get this right.

I would be grateful for any help in these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note:

- There is no need to reference AWS credentials within your code files. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a configuration file. Boto will then automatically find and use them.
- In your Part 1 second code block, it is referencing `outputfilename` but that value is not being set anywhere in the loop. Hence, the incorrect output.
- When downloading a file, if the filename contains folders (eg `020/12/dagsrapport-2020-12-09.csv`), then make sure those folders already exist on your local disk. Or, change the slashes into something else.

Here's some code you might want to expand upon:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('MYBUCKET')

# If you want a list of Keys, use:
key_list = [object.key for object in bucket.objects.all()]
print(key_list)

# Or, if you want to loop through each object and download them
for object in bucket.objects.all():
    filename = object.key.replace('/', '_')
    object.Object().download_file(filename)
    print(filename)
```

Remember: The [boto3 documentation for Amazon S3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) is your friend!